# Restoring corrupt database - "mdf is not a primary database file"

Tags: sql-server, restore

Unfortunately the hard disk of my system is damaged. I am trying to recover my database, but it cannot be attached again to SQL management studio 2005. The error is

> myfile.mdf is not a primary database file. (SQL server , error 5171)